# "NoReverseMatch at/" no Django, quando tento colocar um link no botão

Tags: django, django-templates

Quando tento colocar um *link* em um botão aparece uma página com erro de `NoReverseMatch at/`, não sei mais o que faço, quero colocar esse *link* para ir para um *app* de cadastro de usuários que se chama `login`.

```
<button href="{% url "login.views.registrar" %}" class="btn btn-danger">Cadastre-se</button>
```

> Exception Type:    NoReverseMatch
>   Exception Value:
>
> Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 >pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Experimente remover as aspas das tags `url`. Ex.: `{% url article.views.post_new %}` em vez de `{% url "article.views.post_new" %}`. Veja [essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4981026/520779) para mais detalhes (se o problema for esse mesmo, comente dizendo se funcionou, e eu posto como resposta, acho que depende da versão). A propósito, quando fizer uma pergunta por favor inclua os trechos de código relevantes, não somente um link externo. No caso de um erro envolvendo exceções, um *stack trace* normalmente ajuda também. Fique à vontade para [edit] sua pergunta se quiser/puder.

Comment: Não funcionou tirando as aspas.
Obrigado pela dica da formatação, acho que é desse jeito agora né? :D

Comment: Eu reparei que no [seu `urls.py`](https://github.com/allancarlos123/ajuda_blog/blob/master/blog/urls.py) não há nenhum padrão referenciando a `login.views.registrar`, nem uma inclusão do [`login/urls.py`](https://github.com/allancarlos123/ajuda_blog/blob/master/login/urls.py) (tal como você fez com o `article` - `url(r'', include('article.urls'))`). Se nenhuma URL roteia para aquela *view*, então não tem como criar um link pra ela. Experimente incluir no seu `urls.py` [principal] algo como `url(r'login/', include('login.urls'))` (só um exemplo).

Comment: **Funcionou** perfeitamente @mgibsonbr.
Em base ficou assim
`<a href="{% url "login.views.registrar" %}" class="btn btn-danger">Cadastre-se</a>`
Na urls principal
`url(r'login/', include('login.urls'))`
Com algumas modificações por fora, como o link do template em views.
`return render(request, "login/registrar.html", {"form": UserCreationForm() })`

Answer (score 1):

Um erro `NoReverseMatch` é consequência do Django não conseguir achar uma URL no seu sistema de mapeamento que resolva para uma determinada *view*, seja no template (tag `url`) ou no código Python (`reverse`). No seu caso, o erro está dando ao tentar formar uma URL para `login.views.registrar`, então é preciso ver se há algum padrão no `urls.py` que mapeie para essa *view*.

No seu [exemplo completo](https://github.com/allancarlos123/ajuda_blog) (na [revisão original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/79944/1) da pergunta) eu vejo que não há nada no `urls.py` principal (o do projeto) que roteie para qualquer *view* de `login`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('article.urls'))
]
```

Como você já possui um `urls.py`na app `login`, com um mapeamento para o *view* desejado:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^registrar/new/$', views.registrar, name='registrar'),
]
```

Então tudo o que você precisa fazer é acrescentar uma rota para a app `login`, tal como você fez para `article`. O tipo de URL é você que escolhe, mas a título de exemplo, assumindo que seu site esteja em `http://example.com/django/` e você configure seu `urlpatterns` desse jeito:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('article.urls'))
    url(r'login/', include('login.urls'))
]
```

Então a tag `{% url "login.views.registrar" %}` será substituída por:

```
http://example.com/django/login/registrar/new/
```

E essa URL servirá o resultado da *view* `login.views.registrar`. Fique à vontade para escolher outro roteamento, se desejar, o importante é que **algum** roteamento para a *view* exista, de modo a evitar o `NoReverseMatch`.